# Can I merge independent samples collected by the same survey?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, equivalence, scale-invariance

I have 3 independent data sets collected from the same population using an identical survey design. They are about consumer attitudes toward foreign products, so, 3 countries of origin were used but everything was measured using the same scale measures (identical items). An EFA and CFA were conducted for every scale measure in each sample separately. Model invariance cross groups was ascertained for each measurement model cross groups and also for the overall measurement model. Reliability, convergent and discriminant validity were verified. Also, structural model equivalence was ascertained across groups.

Taking into consideration that my purpose is to test my hypothesis in general and not according to each country of origin, i.e., I need to verify if country of origin and animosity will affect consumer attitudes in general, my questions are:

1. Basing on all previous discussion, can I merge the 3 datasets in one
   dataset and do the path analysis? Or I have to treat each dataset
   separately in path analysis?
2. If I was allowed to merge the 3 data sets in one, should I treat the
   new overall dataset using multi-group analysis or conducting a
   traditional path analysis?

I need some references for this.

Comment: If everything is invariant, then multiple group analysis with all parameters constrained to equality will be the same as a single group model.